# « Fais gaffe ! » (ou juste « Gaffe ! »)

Tags: expressions, registre-familier, origine-ou-raison, interjections

À première vue, on pourrait s'attendre à ce que « fais gaffe » soit analogue à « fais attention » mais, dans le cas de gaffe, la gaffe est précisément ce que l'on souhaite éviter. À quoi ceci est-il dû ?

Je me mets à la place de quelqu'un découvrant l'expression, il lui semblerait sans doute que c'est un ordre lui indiquant de faire une gaffe. *Gaffe* change-t-il de sens dans ce cas bien spécifique ? S'il y a omission, elle me semble bien trop importante.

Comment: Je ne suis pas bien sûr de comprendre ce que tu veux dire par « le *sujet* est ce que l’on souhaite éviter. » Le sujet de « faire » reste la personne à qui l’on s’adresse : dans « Fais gaffe ! », c’est une deuxième personne du singulier. Si l’on s’adresse à plusieurs autres personnes, l’on dira « Faîtes gaffe ! », etc. À moins que tu ne te demande pourquoi  l’on retrouve « gaffe » dans « faire gaffe » et « faire une gaffe » ?

Comment: @Édouard C'est pourquoi j'ai utilisé l'italique : je ne parle pas du sujet grammaticale mais de ce qui nous intéresse (le sujet).

Comment: T'es sûr qu'il ne faut pas utiliser du gras souligné avec des pointillés sur fond rouge dans ce cas là ? ;-) J'ai tenté de reformuler.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Gaffer* est un vieux verbe argotique ou populaire signifiant « veiller » ([sens 3](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gaffer//2) du TLF), plutôt par un garde ou un policier. « Fais gaffe » a le même sens que « fais attention ! ». Il n'y a aucun rapport avec les homographes de *gaffe*. On peut utiliser « Gaffe ! » à la place de « Attention ! » si l'on est pressé.